# require is not defined - Create array of every file in a directory

Tags: javascript, php, web, require, fs

Here is a snippet of an inline `<script>` in my HTML

```html
<script>
var fs = require('fs');
var images = fs.readdirSync('/i/cats/');
</script>
```

I host my website at 000webhost (free version)

My problem is this throws a `ReferenceError, require is not defined`

To be clear, I am trying to find the files on the server, not on the client.

***EDIT***
JavaScript in html is client-side, so require doesn't work. Therefor i have to use PHP, here is what i got so far:

```
<?php
$images = array();
if ($handle = opendir('/i/cats')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        array $images = array_push(array $images, $entry);
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

It seems like it take the directory from the root of the server. How can i fix this?

Comment: This doesn't work because it is client-side code. This would probably work on a node.js host as a back-end script (not included in your HTML), but not front-end.

Comment: Oh, i am new to this. Thanks! But any way i can fix it?

Comment: Write your code into a file.js file and rund it with nodejs like  "node file.js" in terminal , instead of a web browser   https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: *couldn't i use PHP?*

Comment: It depends what server is hosting your files?

Comment: You are you trying to use a node.js object in a html+javascript page. This functions (file system access) are not available in client-side javascript.

Comment: Hmm, but i am hosting i at 000webhost, can i run node.js there?

Comment: You can use a php page using the `readdir` function (http://php.net/manual/es/function.readdir.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Javascript* is one of the few languages that runs both back-end and front-end. This can be confusing, because some tutorials will provide code for the back-end (**node.js**).

While it can run back-end, most webhosts don't provide that option. Even if they do, you would have to read up on the difference before you can combine that with front-end javascript.

What you are currently trying to do, is run server-side code on the client-side (webbrowser).

To run this properly, install *node.js* on your PC and run the script with  node (`node script.js`).

This **cannot** work if you host your files on an **apache** webserver. *000webhost* provides apache. Use PHP instead if you really want this.

Comment: I am now trying to use PHP, but i am new to it, so it is a bit difficult. Don't get how i can find the dir (without starting from the root of the server).

Comment: @Daniel My expertise is JS, not PHP. For the best results please ask a new question (this one won't be read anymore by others). Make sure you show them what you tried with some code.